# How to handle right overflowed inside ListTile flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have listTile to show title and subtitle... here is the code

```
ListTile(
              leading: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
              ),
              title: Text("name xxx"),
              subtitle: 
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "xxxxxxxx",
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' - ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "yyyyyyyyyy",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              trailing: ...
            )
```

when I replace `xxxxxx` and `yyyyyyy` with long sentences... I got `right overflowed by 69 pixels` so, is there a way to show my long subtitle and to prevent this problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have lots of potential solutions to your problem, i can suggest you two simple options:

#### Option 1

If you absolutely need to show all the content of the two Text widget, you can wrap them inside a [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html), rather than in a `Row`:

```
ListTile(
  leading: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
  ),
  title: Text("name xxx"),
  subtitle: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Wrap(
        children: [
          Text(
            "long text yeah long text long long and very long",
          ),
          Text(
            ' - ',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "Another quite long stuff, it's veeery long and by no means short",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Result of Option 1]

#### Option 2

If you need your Row, with all its children, to stay within a single line of text, you can wrap your Text widgets with a [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) and instruct them to handle a potential overflow (maybe with an ellipsis):

```
ListTile(
  leading: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    child: Icon(Icons.fingerprint),
  ),
  title: Text("name xxx"),
  subtitle: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Text(
              "long text yeah long text long long and very long",
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            ' - ',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: Text(
              "Another quite long stuff, it's veeery long and by no means short",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10.0,
              ),
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Result of Option 2]

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the `Text` widget with an `Expanded` widget:

```
                    children: [
                      const Expanded(child:
                      Text(
                        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' - ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Expanded(child:
                      Text(
                        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: Hi, inside my subtitle I have 2 long sentences...they are "xxx" and "yyy" then...I have tried your code but I still get right overflowed by 69 pixels... is there something that I should add more

Comment: it works :D and I have also tried using ```Flexible``` and it works too, thank you very much for your helps